# Thread pooling configurability in Finagle

Tags: multithreading, scala, netty, finagle

Let's assume I've got two Finagle services, as per below

```
val service1: Service[http.Request, http.Response] = ???
val service2: Service[http.Request, http.Response] = ???
```

and I run them both against different ports

```
val server1 = Http.serve(":9090", service1)
val server2 = Http.serve(":8080", service2)
```

- would requests coming to these 2 servers be handled by different Netty worker/thread pools?
- if not, is there a way to configure Finagle so they would be handled by different Netty worker/thread pools?

Comment: Looks like it can be handled with whatever you will provide: https://gist.github.com/vastdevblog/2022320#file-exampleserver-scala-L115

Comment: @michaJlS thanks. however, in this example multiple pools are used to run services after the request has been served. I am interested in using separated Netty worker pools to handle the incoming requests, if possible.

Comment: @StefanoBonetti: The response of one of the Finagle committers in the following (old) post suggests that, when running two Finagle services on a single JVM, the answer to your first question is "no": https://groups.google.com/d/topic/finaglers/HKmj2xJRrNM/discussion

Answer (score 0):

If you are using netty 3, you can set up execution handlers in a pipeline.

http://netty.io/3.5/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/execution/ExecutionHandler.html

Then transform the channel pipeline into a Finagle Codec, which offers builder  methods to create a stack client or stack server, and just set the netty3 threadpool size to 0, finagle has been moving towards, hiding netty from it's users which can be a pain when you're trying to get fine grained control.

Hopefully that works, since I see no reason to do that when you can just run the servers in separate jvm instances.